# VS code - Source Control panel tracking wrong directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I keep getting over 5000+ changes in the Source Control panel every time I install an extension. How do I stop this from happening?

Thanks

edit: it seems to be tracking from my /users directory (my name)

Comment: You're doing something wrong.  What changes are you seeing? What source control & what directory?

Comment: So this happened after I installed an extension - makes sense because extensions can have large numbers of files. However, when I tried to do a git push last night, even when running 'git add .' from a subfolder, it tried to add ALL the files in my /users root folder! I think Git is pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: TL&DR - changes: many, many small .json files, .js files - all types. It is looking in my /user directory not the project directory for modified files. Source control - Git. thanks @SLaks

Comment: Sounds like you turned your entire user profile into a git repo.  Don't do that.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking I did. Hopefully undoing that will fix